# Why is getFragmentManager().findFragmentById returning null (causing NullPointerException)

Tags: android, android-fragments, nullpointerexception, fragmenttransaction

I have two fragments: input on top, and result on bottom.

Initially, only the InputFragment shows.  When the user clicks the "Calculate" button, the ResultFragment shows. That all works well.

The ResultFragment has a "Clear all" button, which I want to clear the InputFragment's fields, and make ResultFragment go away (hide, remove, or detach, I don't care which, so long as it becomes invisible).

But it crashes when you hit "Clear all" button. Specifically, a fatal `NullPointerException` happens in clearResult() method.

Here is MainActivity.java

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements InputFragment.InputFragmentListener, ResultFragment.ResultFragmentListener {

    private static FragmentManager manager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if(savedInstanceState == null){
            Fragment inputFragment  = new InputFragment();

            manager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_top,inputFragment).commit();
        }
    }

    //This gets called by the Input Fragment when the user clicks the Calculate button
    @Override
    public void createResult(String resultPhrase) {

        ResultFragment resultFragment = (ResultFragment) manager.findFragmentById(R.id.result_fragment);

        if (resultFragment != null){
            /* if resultFragment is available, we can modify it's TextView
             * by calling the method to do the updating
             */
            //ResultFragment.theResultText.setText(resultPhrase);
            resultFragment.setResultText(resultPhrase); 
        }else{
            /*...otherwise the fragment has to be created */
            ResultFragment newResultFragment = new ResultFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putString(ResultFragment.resultTxt, resultPhrase);
            newResultFragment.setArguments(args);

            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();   
            transaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container_bottom, newResultFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();       

            //((TextView) newResultFragment.getView().get).setText(resultPhrase);

        }


    }


    //This gets called in the ResultFragment when the user clicks the Clear All button
    @Override
    public void clearResult() {
        //InputFragment inp_frag = (InputFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_input);


        // This damned object is null again 
        //inp_frag.clearFields();
        Fragment res_frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("resultfragtag");

        FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();  
        //res_frag.clearResult();
        transaction.hide(res_frag);
        transaction.commit();   

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Here are the LogCat messages:

> 03-01 23:30:34.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   03-01 23:30:34.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): Process: com.example.amortizersandbox, PID: 3399
>   03-01 23:30:34.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3399): java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to write to field 'int android.app.Fragment.mNextAnim' on a null object reference
>   03-01 23:30:34.663: E/AndroidRuntime(3399):     at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:797)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For replacing/adding fragment use:

```
getSupportFragmentManager()
                            .beginTransaction()
                            .setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_in_top,
                                    R.anim.slide_out_top)
                            .add(R.id.list_frame, fr, "tag").commit();
```

Now for finding this fragment use:

```
Fragment fr = getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag("tag");
        if (fr != null) {
            //do your stuff
        } else {
//fr is null here
        }
```

Comment: This is also a nice answer.  Key point I missed in my code: adding tag name IN THE TRANSACTION (I was adding in the xml of the fragment--that did not work).  Thank you so much!

Comment: Where is the 'correct' button?  (I've seen that comment 1000 times before, but only recently started asking questions, and don't know how to mark it correct. --completely not obvious.)

Comment: Ah, it's the "intuitive" check icon.

Comment: there is tick mark below vote up and down from there you can tick it right.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use tag "resultfragtag" when adding InputFragment.

Try adding it onCreate:

```
 transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_top,inputFragment,"resultfragtag").commit();
```

Comment: Thank you everybody!  Everybody pointed to the use of the tag instead of the id.  I didn't know to add the tag IN THE TRANSACTION -- I put it in the xml of the fragment.  So this little hint really did the job.  (except that it has the input and result fragment mixed up, but that's easy to see and correct if anyone's using this example).

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
Fragment res_frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.result_fragment);
```

replace:

```
Fragment res_frag = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("resultfragtag");
```