# Why does hiding a Fragment cause a null pointer exception?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

## Update 1:

I saw [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28804540/3951400) which solved the issue but I don't understand why and [feel like this guy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYrpk.png).

Both these return a non-null InfoboxFragments but the transaction *fails with the first one*.

```
childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infobox_fragment)
childFragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("plz")
```

**Excuse me?!**

---

## Update 2:

childFragmentManager does not play nice with nested fragments in xml.

---

I've been trying to hide a Fragment inside of another Fragment for a while. I've tried a few approaches and reducing the child fragments height to 1dp seems the most reliable, *but it leaves a bit of the fragment visible*.

So, I tried a recommended approach of using the childFragmentManager with transactions to hide the fragment like below.

The Android docs says this about the `hide(fragment)` method:

> Hides an existing fragment. This is only relevant for fragments whose
>   views have been added to a container, as this will cause the view to
>   be hidden

So, I've contained the fragment inside a `LinearLayout`.

The `showInfoBox()` works fine but the `hideInfoBox()` crashes with a NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.view.ViewGroup.startViewTransition(android.view.View)' on a null object reference
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.completeShowHideFragment(FragmentManager.java:1681)
                                                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1778)
```

The only difference seems to be the `hide` and `show` transactions.

```
    private fun showInfoBox() {
        val infoboxFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infobox_fragment) as InfoboxFragment

        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .show(infoboxFragment)
                .commit()

        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(constraintLayout)
        applyConstraintSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)

    }
```

and

```
    private fun hideInfoBox() { // this crashes
        val infoboxFragment = childFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.infobox_fragment) as InfoboxFragment

        childFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                        android.R.animator.fade_out)
                .hide(infoboxFragment) // with only this difference
                .commit()
    }
```

The fragment is added like so:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

    val infoboxFragment = InfoboxFragment()
    with(childFragmentManager) {
        beginTransaction().add(R.id.infobox_fragment_container, infoboxFragment).commit()
        //beginTransaction().hide(infoboxFragment).commit()
    }

    resetConstraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    applyConstraintSet.clone(constraintLayout)
    //applyConstraintSet.setVisibility(R.id.infobox_fragment_container, View.VISIBLE)
    applyConstraintSet.constrainHeight(R.id.infobox_fragment_container, 250.toDP())
}
```